# Looking for help: Explaining assembly code generated by C compiler

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64

I am trying to understand the assembly instructions generated by the following C code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>

int main()
{    
  char *happy[2];
  happy[0] = "/bin/sh";
  happy[1] = NULL;
  execve(happy[0],happy,NULL);    
}
```

Unfortunately I can't understand this assembly code.
Can anybody explain this code to me? I can figure out that `rax` contains the address of `/bin/sh`, but I don't know the use of the `rsi` register here.

```
 Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x0000000000400a0d <+0>:     push   %rbp
   0x0000000000400a0e <+1>:     mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x0000000000400a11 <+4>:     sub    $0x20,%rsp
   0x0000000000400a15 <+8>:     mov    %fs:0x28,%rax
   0x0000000000400a1e <+17>:    mov    %rax,-0x8(%rbp)
   0x0000000000400a22 <+21>:    xor    %eax,%eax
   0x0000000000400a24 <+23>:    lea    0x8c4d9(%rip),%rax        # 0x48cf04
   0x0000000000400a2b <+30>:    mov    %rax,-0x20(%rbp)
   0x0000000000400a2f <+34>:    movq   $0x0,-0x18(%rbp)
   0x0000000000400a37 <+42>:    mov    -0x20(%rbp),%rax
   0x0000000000400a3b <+46>:    lea    -0x20(%rbp),%rcx
   0x0000000000400a3f <+50>:    mov    $0x0,%edx
   0x0000000000400a44 <+55>:    mov    %rcx,%rsi
   0x0000000000400a47 <+58>:    mov    %rax,%rdi
   0x0000000000400a4a <+61>:    callq  0x432b10 <execve>
   0x0000000000400a4f <+66>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x0000000000400a54 <+71>:    mov    -0x8(%rbp),%rdx
   0x0000000000400a58 <+75>:    xor    %fs:0x28,%rdx
   0x0000000000400a61 <+84>:    je     0x400a68 <main+91>
   0x0000000000400a63 <+86>:    callq  0x435730 <__stack_chk_fail_local>
   0x0000000000400a68 <+91>:    leaveq
   0x0000000000400a69 <+92>:    retq
End of assembler dump.
`
```

Comment: _I am trying to understand_... _but i cant uderstand_ ... _can anybody explian_ Please **visit** the **[help center](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)** and take the tour to see what and how to ask. HINT: Post codes and efforts –

Comment: rdi and rsi are the 2 parameters being passed into execve.  Remember that with at&t syntax, `mov %rcx,%rsi` mean "move rcx into rsi".

Comment: Looks like you have compiled the code with optimizations turned off. Such code is typically harder to understand than optimized code due to all the useless instructions the compiler is not allowed to remove.

Comment: `rsi` is `happy` as it is the second argument to `execve`. See [calling convention documentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#System_V_AMD64_ABI).

Comment: I improved the formulation of the question and the title.

Comment: thanks @Jester for your help. i figured out that rsi rdi and rdx are the 1st 2nd and 3rd arguments to the function.